# Cardinality of a coxeter group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

Let ${G}$ be a Coxeter group with the next presentation 
\begin{equation}
G = \left\langle s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_{n-1} : (s_is_{i+1})^3=1 , \ (s_is_j)^2=1 \ ,\ |i-j| > 1 \right\rangle
\end{equation}
Where $S=\{s_1,\cdots,s_{n-1}\}$ denote the set of generators of the group

I need to prove that $G \cong S_n $.

For that, I define a function $\phi : S \longrightarrow S_n $ by $\phi(s_i)=(i,i+1)$. it is clear that the images of this function satisfy the relations of the group G, so I can extend $\phi$ to a homomorphism $\widetilde\phi:G \longrightarrow S_n$. This homomorphism is surjective, hence $|G| \geq n!$, so if i can show that $|G|\leq n!$ then $\widetilde\phi$ is a isomorphism.

My idea is:

I denote by $S_k=\{s_1,\cdots,s_{k} \}$ and $G_k=\left\langle S_k : (s_is_{i+1})^3=1 , \ (s_is_j)^2=1 \ ,\ |i-j| > 1   \right\rangle$.

I want to prove that $|G_k|\leq (k+1)!$

Some hint?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that it's the symmetry group of the (n-1)-dimensional simplex?

Comment: no, because I don't have that isomorphism explicitly

Comment: You should probably look for a set of cardinal $n$ on which $G$ acts faithfully.

Comment: But the question is how I prove that the action is faithful. because I can define an action on the generators and then extends it to the whole group, I don't have information about the elements of the group

Comment: Ok, if you already have done some work that's cool, but you might want to consider editing your question to show this work, so that people can help you in the most efficient way. For instance, what is the set you are acting on? What is the action?

Comment: Ok, you are right. I'll edit the question to show what I really want. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I happen to have a proof of this result in some lecture notes, I will cut and paste it here. You will see that it uses Proposition ???, so you will need to figure out what that says! Note also that permutations are composed from left to right.

*Theorem* Let $ G_n := \langle X \mid R_1 \cup R_2 \cup R_3 \rangle $, where
\begin{align*}
X & := \{x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\} \\
R_1 & := \left\{ x_i^2 = 1 : 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \right\} \\
R_2 & := \left\{ (x_ix_{i+1})^3 = 1 : 1 \leq i \leq n-2 \right\} \\
R_3 & := \left\{ (x_ix_j)^2 = 1 : 1 \leq i < j-1 \leq n-2 \right\}
\end{align*}
Then $ G_n \cong S_n $ by $ x_i \mapsto \tau_i =(i,i+1)$.

*Proof* By the fundamental theorem, $ x_i \mapsto \tau_i $ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n-1 $ extends to a homomorphism $ \theta : G_n \to S_n $, and in fact $ \theta $ is an epimorphism as $ S_n $ is generated by the $ \tau_i $, so $ |G_n| \geq |S_n| = n! $.

To show that $ |G_n| \leq |S_n| $, we use induction on $ n $. We have $ G_1 =
\langle \varnothing \mid \varnothing \rangle $, so $ G_1 = \{1\} $ and $ |G_1|
= 1 $. For $ n = 2 $, $ G_2 = \langle x_1 \mid x_1^2 \rangle \cong C_2 $, so $
|G_2| = 2 $, which is fine.
Note that $ G_3 = D(2,2,3) \cong D_{6} \cong S_3 $. Now we assume that $ |G_n|
\leq n! $, and aim to show that $ |G_{n+1}| \leq (n+1)! $.

Let $ H := \langle x_2,\ldots,x_n \rangle \leq G_{n+1} $. Since the relations
of $ G_n $ on generators of $ H $ are all in $ R_1 \cup R_2 \cup R_3 $, we may
apply induction to get $ |H| \leq n! $. We now aim to express $ G_{n+1} $ as
a union of $ n+1 $ cosets of $ H $ to get $ |G_{n+1}| \leq (n+1)! $.

Note that the stabiliser of 1 in $S_{n+1}$ is
$ \langle \tau_2,\ldots,\tau_n \rangle $ By the Orbit-Stabiliser
Theorem, the $n+1$ coset representatives of this subgroup in $S_{n+1}$
map 1 to $1,2,\ldots,n+1$.  Since $ 1_{S_{n+1}} : 1 \mapsto 1 $, $ \tau_1 : 1
\mapsto 2 $, $ \tau_1\tau_2 : 1 \mapsto 3 $ etc, we see that $
\{1,\tau_1,\tau_1\tau_2,\ldots,\tau_1\cdots\tau_n\} $ is a set of coset
representatives. So we will try to prove the result by showing that
$\{1,x_1,x_1x_2,\ldots,x_1\cdots x_n\} $ is a set of coset representatives
of $H$ in $G_{n+1}$.

To do that, we will use Proposition ??? with
$ S = Hg_0 \cup Hg_1 \cup \cdots \cup H g_n, $
where $ g_0 = 1 $, $ g_1 = x_1 ,\ldots, g_i = x_1 \cdots x_i $ for
$ 1 \leq i \leq n $. We need to prove that $ g_ix_j \in S $
for $0 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$.
Then Proposition ??? gives $ G = S $, so $ |G| =
|S| \leq (n+1)|H| \leq (n+1)!$, and we are done. There are four cases:

1. [$ j > i+1 $]. For $k\le i$, we have
   $ (x_kx_j)^2 = 1 \Rightarrow x_j^{-1}x_k^{-1} = x_kx_j $,
   and so $ x_jx_k = x_kx_j $.
   Hence $ g_ix_j = x_1 \cdots x_ix_j = x_jx_1 \cdots x_i = x_jg_i $.
   But $ j \geq 2 $, so $ x_j \in H $. Hence $ x_jg_i \in Hg_i \subseteq S $.
2. [$ j = i+1 $] We have $ g_ix_j = g_{i+1} \in S $.
3. [$ i = j $] This implies that
   $ g_ix_i = x_1 \cdots x_{i-1}x_i^2 = x_1 \cdots x_{i-1} = g_{i-1} $ and
   $ g_{i-1} \in S $.
4. [$ i > j $] Since $g_0=1$, we can assume that $j \ge 1$.
   Note that $ (x_jx_{j+1})^3=1 $, so $ x_jx_{j+1}x_j = x_{j+1}x_jx_{j+1} $,
   since $ x_j^2 = x_{j+1}^2 = 1 $, so
   \begin{align*}
    g_ix_j & = x_1 \cdots x_ix_j \\
    & = x_1 \cdots x_jx_{j+1}x_{j+2} \cdots x_ix_j \\
    & = x_1 \cdots x_jx_{j+1}x_jx_{j+2} \cdots x_i \\
    & = x_1 \cdots x_{j-1}x_{j+1}x_jx_{j+1}x_{j+2} \cdots x_i \\
    & = x_{j+1}x_1 \cdots x_{j-1}x_jx_{j+1} \cdots x_i
    \end{align*}
   Since $ j+1 \geq 2 $, $ x_{j+1} \in H $, so $ g_ix_j \in Hg_i \subseteq S $.

So $ g_ix_j \in S$ for all $ 0 \leq i \leq n $ and $1 \leq j \leq n $,
and we are done.